# Accessing OData Query

Tags: acumatica

I plan to use PowerBI and access Acumatica Azure Site from OData Query.

The Acumatica Installation is on Azure https://commtexdemo61.cloudapp.net and I am able to get the XML from https://commtexdemo61.cloudapp.net/odata/Company using my userid : admin and Password : sameer. This is having the Rapidbyte Demo.

Acumatica is displayed as Untrusted !

However when accessing through Excel/PowerBI - I am getting an error : The underline connection is closed. Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

How to solve this !

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-signed SSL certificate. It is not trusted by web browsers or by PowerBI. You've probably noticed that you get a similar warning when connecting using your browser. You have two options:

1. Use an unencrypted connection / HTTP instead of HTTPS
2. Get a trusted certificate from an authority like Comodo or Verisign (there are hundreds of options - just Google for SSL certificates)

Comment: http://commtexdemo61.cloudapp.net/odata/Company points back to https://commtexdemo61.cloudapp.net.

Comment: Acumatica Azure Packages require Acumatica Certificate loaded on Windows Azure, which is also available in the Trusted store of the Web Browser.

Comment: Even though If I take a SSL Certificate how can the Acumatica Medium Package shall understand the new certificate used. Just by loading in the Cloud service, will it work ??

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the process for the Acumatica Azure Package. But a portion of the configuration has to be done on the Azure portal itself - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site

Comment: The link provided does not help as it talks about the Azure App Service. The Acumatica Package is loaded as a Cloud Service and is scaled in Azure.

Comment: Any example of Odata used with Acumatica for the Cloud Service on Azure ??

Comment: You might want to contact Acumatica/Azure support directly - this is not a programming question and beyond the type of assiance that can be provided on StackOverflow.